# Rudin 1.17: why is it obvious that $\phi$ is a Borel function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

In rudin 1.17, we prove that any positive measurable function can be approximated by positive measurable simple functions. So, we construct such functions using small intervals: $$\phi_n(x) = \begin{cases}k_n(t)\delta_n,\text{ if t < n}\\ n\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Here, $\delta_n = 2^{-n}$ and $k_n(t)$ is a positive integer such that $k_n(t)\delta_n \leq t < (k_n(t) + 1)\delta_n$.
After the construction is done, Rudin concludes that "Each $\phi_n$ is then a Borel function on $[0, \infty]$."

I could try and prove that the preimage of any open set lies in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets of $[0, \infty]$, but it seems pretty hard :)

So, why is it so obvious that $\phi_n$ is a Borel function?

Comment: http://abstrusegoose.com/12 :-)

Comment: For example, the monotonicity of $\phi_n$ yields the result. Every monotonic function on $\mathbb{R}$ or subsets thereof is Borel measurable.

Comment: @DanielFischer: It is funny that Rudin doesn't give this statement before the theorem... He only gives the definition and some properties (ex: 1.12 b: the preimage of any Borel set is measurable if $f$ is measurable), but it's not enough to prove that $\phi_n$ is Borel :(

Comment: You have the criterion of Thm. 1.12, (c). For monotonically increasing functions, $f^{-1}((\alpha,+\infty])$ is always either $[x,+\infty)$ or $(x,+\infty)$ for some $x \in [-\infty,+\infty)$.

Comment: If $f$ takes on only finitely many values $y_1, \dots y_m$ and each $f^{-1}(\{y_k\})$ is measurable, then $f$ is measurable. Proof: For any open $U, f^{-1}(U)$ is just a finite union of some of the $f^{-1}(\{y_k\}).$

Comment: @zhw.: Yes, but it doesn't seem to prove that $f$ is Borel...

Comment: @DanielFischer We're on an abitrary measurable space $X.$ And even when $X=\mathbb R,$ the $\phi_n$ are in general far from monotonic.

Comment: @zhw. No, $\phi_n \colon [0,+\infty] \to [0,+\infty)$. Okay, not quite a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but the difference is trivial.

Comment: @Igor It doesn't really make sense to talk about $f$ being Borel measurable because $X$ is not a topological space.

Comment: @DanielFischer Have you read 1.17 in Rudin Real and Complex Analysis? We are approximating an arbitrary nonnegative measurable function $f$ by simple functions on an arbitrary measurable space.

Comment: @zhw. I have. The approximating functions will be $s_n = \phi_n \circ f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer OK, but this is nothing like the 1.17 I see in RCA second edition.

Comment: @zhw. Aha. I have the third. I wonder how it looks in the second.

Comment: @zhw. The $s_n$ are the same in the second edition, just more directly defined. The proof in the third edition is shorter due to the introduction of the $\phi_n$.

Comment: @zhw.: Ok, so I thought when you were talking about $f$ as measurable, you meant $\phi$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: So, the Thm 1.12 (c) gives the criterion for measurability of $f$, and to prove that $f$ is Borel, I have to show that $f^{-1}((\alpha, \infty])$ is in borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets of $[0, \infty]$, and that's what your comment shows, right? Just to make sure that I understand it well enough...

Comment: Dang, I used $f$ for a monotonically increasing function. Now I don't know which $f$ you mean. If you mean the monotonic function $[0,+\infty] \to [0,+\infty]$, then yes, that's what you need to see.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @DanielFischer: yes, I actually meant to write $\phi$ instead of $f$. I think that it would be nice to produce the result in the form of an answer. I would write one, but I don't want to steal your merit. Could you write a short resume as the answer to this question, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All monotonic functions $g \colon A \to [-\infty,+\infty]$, where $A$ is a subset of $[-\infty,+\infty]$, are Borel measurable. If $g$ is increasing (non-strictly or strictly), for all $\alpha \in (-\infty,+\infty)$ we have either $g^{-1}((\alpha,+\infty]) = (x,+\infty] \cap A$ or $g^{-1}((\alpha,+\infty]) = [x,+\infty] \cap A$ for some $x \in [-\infty,+\infty]$, and if $g$ is decreasing, the preimages are either $[-\infty,x)\cap A$ or $[-\infty,x] \cap A$. These sets are open resp. closed in $A$, hence they are Borel sets. By the criterion in 1.12 (c), it follows that a monotonic function is Borel measurable.

Then, 1.12 (d) asserts that the approximating functions $s_n = \phi_n \circ f$ are measurable.